# Send Json from PHP to React Native

Tags: php, json, react-native

So I have a josn object which has an array of objects which I want to send to a react native app through https but the problem is that I get null in react native

The code of the php :

```
<?php
class Product {
    // Properties
    public $title;
    public $price; 
  }
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$ProductList =array();
$aa=$a->{'shopping_results'};
foreach($aa as $y => $y_value) {
    $product = new Product();
   $product->{'title'} =  $y_value ->{'title'};
   $product->{'price'} = $y_value ->{'price'};
    array_push($ProductList,$product);
}
echo $x=json_encode(array('listx' => $ProductList),JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);// the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE for the Arabic letters
?>
```

When I try to view the content of this json on the browser this is what I get
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXT4X.png

```
The react native code

 await fetch(URL, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
            // , body: JSON.stringify({ name: "tea" })
        })
            .then((response) => response.text()) //tried .json() got JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson);//This prints blank
                console.log("hi");

                this.setState({ output: responseJson });//nothing shows

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
```

**Note:** I tried to receive a text from HTTPs request and it worked (The connection is fine)

Comment: Why do you have the `$x= ` part in `echo $x=json_encode...`?

Comment: `response.data` is usually where the json would be

Comment: I did that because I wanted to try to decode the json it was just for testing if the encoding was right

Comment: Remove the `$x=`, it's not adding anything of benefit, and is possibly problematic (not 100% sure)

Comment: @DCTID There is nothing called data I tried but it did not work

Comment: @PatrickQ removed $x still nothing has changed

Comment: Have you tried by removing the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`? So that the json is fully escaped? Which would resolve the `JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF`

Comment: I'm also curious why `.then((response) =>` instead of `.then(response =>` ??

Comment: @IncredibleHat Changed  `.then((response) =>` to `.then(response =>` and removed `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` but still it only prints blank

Comment: Did you also change `.then((responseJson) =>` to `.then(responseJson =>` to follow suit? I'm sure thats valid JS, but I've never used it that way (or recall seeing examples that way). It seems odd the issue you are having, as that json in your image doesn't look like it was truncated (unexpected EOF). And if you are getting an empty console.log, then it means the whole of JS is reaching that point. Baffling.

Comment: @IncredibleHat yes I also changed it to  `.then(responseJson =>`. Yeah, the issue I'm having really made me frustrated I couldn't solve it I tried so many solutions :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to set HTTP headers, methods in your PHP code so as to accept requests from your react native app (basically I'm telling you to implement REST APIs). If already implemented, just make sure you are giving the correct endpoint in your react-native's fetch URL. And one more thing, when you are trying to retrieve data from the server make sure to set method: 'GET'.

If you're a beginner/ don't have prior knowledge about REST APIs, then here's a reference for you : https://www.positronx.io/create-simple-php-crud-rest-api-with-mysql-php-pdo/ I'm sure it'll give you some basic idea about your need.

Comment: And one more reference https://www.onlyxcodes.com/2020/05/php-crud-api-tutorial.html